# plotly with multiple series

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, plotly

I want to replicate this graph below. I have reached a stage where I could reproduce the bar chart in R, using plot_ly. But, I rather failed to add the line segment in the secondary axis. So, can someone help me what I should add in my chart code, to get a similar axis. I have the details and a MWE below.

[image]

I am trying to use plot_ly. Here is my dataframe and what I did:

```
# download data  
if (!file.exists("SCFP2013.xlsx")) {
  download.file("https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/files/scfp2013excel.zip", "SCFP2013.zip")
  unzip("scfp2013.zip")
} 

df <- read_excel("SCFP2013.xlsx")
df[df$NETWORTH < 0, ]$NETWORTH <- 0 # if net worth is less than 0, assign a value of zero

# compute values of retirmet assets 
households2 <- data.frame(
  netWorth = df$NETWORTH,
  weight = df$WGT,
  RETQLIQ = df$RETQLIQ    
)

# group households into segments
households2 <- households2[households2$netWorth >= 10000, ]

# split into net worth segments 
nw2 <- floor(log10(households2$netWorth))
segment2 <- ifelse(nw2 == 4, "     $10k", 
                   ifelse(nw2 == 5, "    $100K", 
                          ifelse(nw2 == 6, "   $1M",               
                                 ifelse(nw2 == 7, "  $10M",               
                                        ifelse(nw2 == 8, " $100M",               
                                               "$1B+"))))) 

# compute average asset distrubtions
results2            <- as.data.frame((aggregate(households2,list(segment2),mean)))
results2$life.cycle <- results2$RETQLIQ/results2$netWorth

plot_ly(results2, x = ~Group.1, y = ~RETQLIQ, type = 'bar', name = 'Retirement (Pension/IRA)') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Millions'), xaxis = list(title = "Net Worth"),
         title = "Pensions Wealth", barmode = 'stack')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding another trace with `type='scatter'` and `mode='lines'` (I named it `life.cycle`) and setting up an additional y-axis in `layout(...)`:

```
plot_ly(results2, x = ~Group.1, y = ~RETQLIQ, 
       type = 'bar', name = 'Retirement (Pension/IRA)') %>%

add_trace(x = ~Group.1, y = ~life.cycle, 
          type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = 'life.cycle', 
          yaxis = 'y2', line = list(color = 'orange')) %>%

  layout(title = "Pensions Wealth", barmode = 'stack',
         xaxis = list(title = "Net Worth"),
         yaxis = list(side="left", title = 'Millions'),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", title = '',
         showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add an additional line over your current plot. Something like below will work. `ay` provides the layout details which you can modify based on your requirement.

```
ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "red"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = ""
)

plot_ly(results2, x = ~Group.1, y = ~RETQLIQ, type = 'bar', name = 'Retirement (Pension/IRA)') %>%
  add_lines(x = ~Group.1, y = ~life.cycle, name = "Life Cycle", yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Millions'), xaxis = list(title = "Net Worth"), yaxis2 = ay,
         title = "Pensions Wealth", barmode = 'stack')
```